# How to pump liquid aerosol?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a use case where I want to produce fog (an aerosol) using an industrial grade high-volume fog generator and then I would like to direct the resulting fog to different locations i.e. small boxes in the same room. This way, I can have concentrated fog where I need and keep rest of the room space clear.

Being a physics noob, I'm running the thought experiment in my head, and I believe since fog too is a fluid, I can just 'pump' it somehow. What kind of pump would one use in case one had to pump fog from one place to another?

Comment: A fog is an aerosol suspension in air, so just use an air pump or fan. The problem is rather if the pump breaks the suspension - I suspect some care is needed there, given that many fogs are fine oil droplets.

Comment: @AndersSandberg And what could be the ways to avoid breaking the suspension?

Comment: I have used a pipe and a small axial fan (like CPU fan) to transport water-mist from the point of generation (which is an ultrasonic mist generator inside a closed container) over distances ~1 meter. Larger distances will be problematic, but you can try.